# Converting DateTime in string with GMT to local time in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a date in a CSV file which is coming as a string to SSIS Script task.

I need to convert the date to the local time based on the GMT offset present in the string - I want to convert it to `datetime` and save it in the DB.

The datetime I am getting is

```
2018-06-21 08:55 GMT-0400
```

I need to store this as

```
2018-06-21 08:55
```

assuming my local time is EST.

For this I am using the following code:

```
 DateTime dt;        // datetime variable
 string str;                // string variable
 string format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
 str = Row.Dateused;

 if (Row.Dateused_IsNull == false)
 {
     // convert datetime format to standard one
     DateTime.TryParseExact(str, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal |DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal,out dt);
     Row.Dateused = dt.ToString();
 }
```

But when I execute it, this is the output I am getting:

```
1/1/0001 12:00:00
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: If you care about timezones use `DateTimeOffset`. BTW storing dates as strings in the database is a *very* serious bug. Use the correct type instead, eg `datetime` or `datetimeoffset` if you care about time, or `date` if you only want a date.

Comment: "The datetime I am getting is

2018-06-21 08:55 GMT-0400
I need to store this as

2018-06-21 08:55"...but in EST the time would be 04:55, not 08:55, so surely if you're storing the times in EST you need to store that value instead? And yes, don't store the date as a string in your database. You shouldn't need to be outputting it as a string again, use a suitable C# class instead. Also consider whether it might be better to store dates as UTC and then present them to the user in the relevant timezone at the time they need to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Version**

The correct pattern for ParseExact is `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 'GMT'zzzzz"`. The best type to use is `DateTimeOffset`.

If `DateTime` is used, it should have the `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` in order to get the UTC time.

In any case, pass the strongly typed value to the database instead of strings to avoid conversion errors.

**Long Version**

The correct type when dealing with timezones is `DateTimeOffset`, not `DateTime`. DateTime doesn't understand timezones so it assumes that times are either UTC or the *local* timezone of the machine that runs this code. It doesn't understand what `local` actually means.

Both DateTime and DateTimeOffset can parse this string using the correct pattern :

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 'GMT'zzzzz"
```

For example :

```
var pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 'GMT'zzzzz";
var dt=DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2018-06-21 08:55 GMT-0400",pattern,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine("{0:O}",dt);
```

Will print :

```
2018-06-21T08:55:00.0000000-04:00
```

The [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2) property can return the date and time without the offset, with DateTimeKind.Unspecified. The following code :

```
 DateTime dtOnly=dt.DateTime;
 Console.WriteLine("{0:O}",dtOnly);
```

Will print :

```
2018-06-21T08:55:00.0000000
```

It's still better to use `datetimeoffset` in the database and avoid errors eg due to daylight time conversions. If the type *has* to be `datetime` (why?) it should be converted to UTC first with [UtcDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.utcdatetime?view=netframework-4.7.2). This will lose the offset information though.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:O}",dt.UtcDateTime);
```

Will print :

```
2018-06-21T12:55:00.0000000Z
```

With DateTimeKind.Utc

*What about DateTime?*

`DateTime.ParseExact` will also work, but the result will depend on the *local* timezone. That's be cause ParseExact will see the offset and return either a DateTime adjusted to the *local* timezone, whatever that is, or to UTC. The only way it will return `08:55` will be if that's the timezone offset of the current machine.

On my machine the offset is +3:00. So

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2018-06-21 08:55 GMT-0400",pattern,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

Will return `2018-06-21T15:55:00` with Kind = Local. Same for `AssumeUniversal` since well, the string isn't UTC, it has an offset.

`DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` will result in `2018-06-21T12:55:00` with Kind Utc as it should. That is the correct the corresponding UTC value which can be stored in the database without causing *too much* confusion,